# Making menu button highlight

Tags: jquery

I am using this example http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/ to make my menu link highlight as a user scrolls down. The problem is the example highlights 'li' tag, but i only want 'a' tag to be highlighted. So I tried doing it this way:

```
if (lastId !== id) {
           lastId = id;
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass("active");
       }
```

I took off parent() from the original code, but this still doesn't achieve what I want. I'm not very good with jQuery yet, so I'm not sure what else to add/remove so only 'a' tag highlights instead of 'li' tag

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/1347/?

Comment: Thanks, you also got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle that highlights the [`a` elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a) instead of the [`li` elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li): [**<kbd>Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/1348/).

What I did was

- changed the HTML, so it is the first `a` element which has class active
  instead of the first `li` element by default:

  `<a class="active" href="#">Top</a>`
- changed the CSS, so the rules for `#top-menu li.active a` become
  `#top-menu li a.active` (so they are applied to the `a` elements).
- changed the JavaScript to work with all of this:

  ```
    menuItems
        .removeClass("active")
        .filter("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass("active");
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize i needed to remove end() function

Answer (score 0):

Your [result on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/1349/).

There was a mistake with `.parent()` (lines 42-43).

I also adapted the HTML markup to correspond:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="active">Top</a>
</li>
```

and CSS:

```
//#top-menu li.active a {
#top-menu li a.active {
```

Comment: @user977151 You specified `menuItems = topMenu.find("a")`, so when you want to set/remove your `active` class on `a` tags you don't need to call `.parent()`.

Comment: I fixed the css and html parts before, I just didn't realize I needed to remove the end() function for the jquery to work. I already removed parent() in my trials and errors...hence why I gave you jquery code without parent()